# related to list and file handling?

Tags: python

I have file with contents in list form such as

```
[1,'ab','fgf','ssd']
[2,'eb','ghf','hhsd']
[3,'ag','rtf','ssfdd']
```

I want to read that file line by line using `f.readline` and assign each line to a list.

I tried doing this:

```
k=[ ]
k=f.readline()
print k[1]
```

I expected a result to show 2nd element in the list in first line, but it showed the first bit and gave o/p as `'1'`.

How to get the expected output?

Comment: is it possible to remove the leading and ending `[]`? Then you could use the builtin CSV parser.

Comment: Is that actual content of your file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`eval`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval) on each line; this would evaluate the the expression in the line and should yield your expected list, if the formatting is correct.

A safer solution would be a simple CSV parser. For that your input could look something like this (comma-separated):

```
123,321,12,123,321,'asd',ewr,'afdg','et al',213
```

Maybe this is feasible.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is to take the input format shown and store it as a list attempting to execute the input file (with [eval()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval)) is not a good idea. This leaves your program open to all sorts of accidentally and intentionally harmful input. You are better advised to just parse the input file:

```
s=f.readline()[1:-1]
k = s.split(',')
print k[1]
```

Comment: Which will however fail if one of the strings contains a `,`.

Comment: @Marian Fair point, but there ways to get around that. They might not take three lines of code though.

Answer (score 1):

readline just returns strings. You need to cast it to what you want. [`eval`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval) does the job, be warned that however it does **execute everything** inside the string, so this is only an option if you trust the input (i.e. you've saved it yourself).

If you need to save data from your program to a file, you might want to use [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html).

Answer (score 1):

if the sample posted is actual content of your file (which I highly doubt), here is what you could do starting with Python 2.6, [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> for line in open(fname):
    print(ast.literal_eval(line)[1])


ab
eb
ag
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You can use eval as suggested, but I'm just curious: Is there any reason not to use `JSON` as file format?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [json](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) module:

```
import json

with open('lists.txt', 'r') as f:
  lines = f.readlines()
  for line in lines:
    line = line.replace("'", '"')
    l = json.loads(line)
    print l[1]
```

Outputs:

```
ab
eb
ag
```